# Remove single(particular) session from browser after 5 mins

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, web-config

How can I remove any particular session 5mins after it's creation. I found this code to define session time out but it removes all sessions. I have many sessions which gets create browsing throughout the website. How can I remove one single session.

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms"/>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="1">
    </sessionState>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Do you actually want to remove any session 5 min after it is created or 5 min of being idle? I'm not good at asp.net but I think you can do it using cookies. Create a cookie that stores last action time and check if currentTime - lastActionTime > 5 min maybe?

Comment: If you want to do it server-side you should take a look at [Quarz.NET](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net). You can shedule a job that runs every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Session.Remove() method;[Session.Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.remove.aspx)

```
Session.Remove("yourSessionName");
```

Comment: How will the time of 5 mins be taken into account?

Comment: This is standard method. How I do in web.config for universal app validation & also to set timeout

Answer (score 0):

- Include this in you web.config file:

  using web.config

  ```
     <sessionState timeout="minutes"/>
  ```

  Using IIS

  Change the following time-outs in Internet Services Manager .Choose a value greater than the default of 20.
- Select Default Web Site > Properties > Home Directory > Application
  Settings > Configuration > Options.

  ```
     Enable the session state time-out and set the Session timeout for 60 minutes.
  ```

  [image]
- Select Application Pools > DefaultAppPool > Properties.
- From the Performance tab under Idle timeout, set Shutdown worker
  processes after being idle for a value higher than 20.

  [image]

  The default session time-out setting on IIS is 5 minutes but it can be increased to a maximum of 24 hours or 1440 minutes.

Comment: If I use <sessionState timeout="minutes"/>  then all session which are created during browsing will get expire after 5 mins right? I want only one particular session to be auto expire